# How I can check current page is home or a special page in template django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to check that current page is home page or not in django template. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that home page url is /, we can check that by

```
{% if request.path == '/' %}
      <h1 id="nameid" class="display-6 fs-3">{{settings.title}}</h1>
{% else %}
      <h2 id="nameid" class="display-6 fs-3">{{settings.title}}</h2>
{% endif %}
```

For other page for example about page, we can use `{% if request.path == '/about/' %}`